# R combining two vectors into one

Tags: r, vector, combinations

Let's say I have two vectors

```
a <- c(NA,"Jan","Feb",NA)
b <- c("Mar",NA,NA,"Apr")
```

How should I combine `a` and `b` so that I can get something like this

```
ab <- c("Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Apr")
```

Remember that here `NA` is different from "NA".

Comment: You don't have "NA" in your vectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `pmax`

```
pmax(a,b, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] "Mar" "Jan" "Feb" "Apr"
```

Or use `ifelse`

```
ifelse(is.na(a), b, a)
#[1] "Mar" "Jan" "Feb" "Apr"
```